# Solve the differential equation - getting weird answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this differential equation:
$$\frac{du}{dr}=\frac{4+\sqrt{r}}{2+\sqrt{u}}$$

I did it and got
$$u=\frac{2r^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}{3\sqrt{u}+2}+\frac{4r}{\sqrt{u}+2}+C$$ but my homework system is marking this as wrong. Why is that?

Comment: Could you outline the approach that you took?

Comment: How is $\frac{4+\sqrt{r}}{2+\sqrt{u}}$ a differential equation?

Comment: This is not helpful. What is the full equation? **How** did you get the answer? *Show your work.*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the differential...I can show you my work in a bit

Comment: How would expressing $u$ in terms of $u$ make sense?

Answer (score 1):

***Just a hint***

$$\frac{du}{dr}=\frac{4+\sqrt{r}}{2+\sqrt{u}}$$
$$(2+\sqrt{u})du=(4+\sqrt{r})dr$$
$$\int(2+\sqrt{u})du=\int(4+\sqrt{r})dr$$
$$2u+\frac 23 u^{3/2}+K=\int(4+\sqrt{r})dr$$
$$..............$$
Do the same for the right side of the equation

Answer (score 0):

you must write $$(2+\sqrt{u})du=(4+\sqrt{r})dr$$ and integrate this!
the solution should be $$4\,r+2/3\,{r}^{3/2}-2\,u \left( r \right) -2/3\, \left( u \left( r
 \right)  \right) ^{3/2}+{\it \_C1}=0
$$